# Regarding the xdotool spammer

Tags: discussion, spam

Some of you who regularly broswe the c++/c#/python (and a few other) tags will probably have run into this guy in the last few days. He's been spamming so with a fairly lengthy post mentioning amongst other things google, amazon and xdotool.

- [Exhibit A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384774/code-why-is-google-using-https-do-they-know-something-we-dont-know-ar)
- [Exhibit B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383531/create-list-array-and-then-merge-with-another-list-array)
- [Exhibit C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382262/array-hangs-up-over-and-over-again)
- [Exhibit D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385350/python-how-to-print-this-code-in-mod-wsgi-script)

These are just a small sample of the posts this guy has made under several different accounts. It's now to the point where when my feed shows the new question pop-up I'm expecting another one of these instead of a legitimate question.

Which leads me to my question. Assuming this hasn't been tried already, considering he always uses roughly the same text, would it be at all feasible to implement a filter on new questions targeting specifically those containing a combination of the words "amazon", "google", "xdotool" ?

Comment: Or we could ignore him and wait for him to go away. In my experience, such trolls get bored after a day or two.

Comment: No I don't think it's feasible. Something like that could easily catch false positives

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ your eyes of disapproval tell me everything I need to know. :)

Comment: Maybe it is not the trolling he's after - maybe he enjoys getting banned! Or maybe it's a 'she' ... with that said it could be a monkey. That's it! My 2 cents is that it is a pet monkey who tries to get her owner's account hell banned!

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ The filter could require the mods to approve the question. I'm just asking if theres a way to keep them from reaching "the masses".

Comment: In addition to false positives, there are way too many ways to get around a literal string block.  How many alternatives do we have to block to completely silence him?

Comment: He'll just change the text to get around the ban.  Yesterday it was soemthing else besides xdotool; he was spamming a link to http://somedomain/sumar_is_gay

Comment: Here's the other relevant meta question about this guy: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193867/how-do-you-deal-with-legitimate-questions-from-a-troll

Comment: @RobertHarvey Your link is broken ;)

Comment: Other related questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194027/who-handles-the-trolls , http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181760/when-enough-is-enough , http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180300/potential-sockpuppets-of-a-troll-that-dont-seem-to-be-trolling-themselves-what . We've tried many approaches with this guy, some of which have slowed him down, but he always comes back. He changes what he posts regularly enough that no filter would be able to stop him for long. The developers are trying something else that sounds like it has the potential to work in the short term.

Comment: Obviously, we should infect his machine with a virus and destroy his software.

Comment: @DeadMG I've started implementing the virus.

Comment: @Borgleader I appreciate someone bringing this up. The guys name is Sumer Kolcak. He apparently is a Turkish immigrant to the US who lost a large amount of money in 2006 and suffered a psychotic break. No, I am not making any of this up. But yes, it would be very nice if we could figure out a way to permanently ban him  that'd be great.

Comment: @EricUrban, On behalf of the community, if it's ok, where did this information come from? I'm sure there would be many people interested in knowing.

Comment: @chris If you just google, 'Sumer Kolcak' he has actually posted his identity cards online. His mad rantings are the common thread between everything. After the masive financial loss, he neglected to settle up with the IRS, which explains his current predicament and attitude towards the government. His original account http://stackoverflow.com/users/2434633/sumer-kolcak?tab=activity