# About "Yet Another Simple Array Question"

Tags: support, specific-question, spam

So there's [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389087/yet-another-super-simple-array-question-on-hold-kinda) that seems to be a bot. It keeps getting closed and deleted, but the OP reposts it pretty quickly.
[The user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2708682/user2708682) seems to be a bot with some built-in search words, which it looks for in comments. If none of them are found, it defaults to "troll". It then inserts the found word in a template response.

How should we go about dealing with this user and such posting behavior? One diagnostic red flag that comes to mind is to pay special attention to posts that tag many programming languages as this one did. If too many programming languages are tagged in a question, it may be indicative of the OP not knowing what they are asking.

Comment: It's just that usual python troll...

Comment: The user has been around for a long time, the mods have been dealing with him for a long time.  They're pretty much already doing everything that they can be doing.  The user is quite...motivated...to continue his malicious behavior, despite any and all actions taken against him.

Comment: Also mentioned here [Regarding the xdotool spammer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194344/145673)

Comment: I think I got one of his posts in an audit...

Comment: @StephenTG So basically it's a conspiracy. The python troll is actually a robo-reviewer who wants to flood the system with so many bad posts that every single audit will be those - thereby making audits easy to spot.

Comment: @Mysticial That's just crazy enough to be true...

Comment: @Mysticial audits are _supposed_ to be easy

Comment: @AndrewBarber: consider that this guy/bot (botguy?) would have to create a new openID each time, and that stuff is hard to script (or am I just a n00b?). So I think there might still be some human elements to this bot